# Перевод градусов Фаренгейта в градусы Цельсия и вывод в форме таблицы

Tags: javascript

Нужно сделать следующие: Пользователь вводит градусы по Фаренгейту, программа считает по формуле  ((наше значение) - 32) / (5/9).  При чем оно должно еще добавлять по 1 значению 5 раз и выводить в виде таблицы.

Вот что у меня есть на данный момент:

```
<form id='temp'>
<input id="t" placeholder="Введите температуру по F"/>
<button onclick='temp()'>Перевести температуру</button> </form>
```

далее я получаю значение из инпута :

```
function temp() {
var t = document.getElementById('t').value;

for (var i = t; i >= t; i++) {
    var c = (i - 32) / (5/9);

    alert(++c); 
}

}
```

Цикл for у меня уже не правильный, я это знаю, но не могу понять как сделать правильно.
Вывод должен быть или через алерт или через document.write, главное что бы все значения появлялись вместе.

Comment: на чистом javascripte надо реализовать?
При вводе одново значения надо виводить 5 последующих
например если ввели 5 то виводить 5, 6, 7, 8, 9?

Comment: Желательно на чистом, но не объязательно.
Да, по-поводу ввода правильно, при вводе одного значения оно выводит это значение и еще 5 следующих....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для постоянно возрастающей переменной цикла i условие `i >= t` истинно всегда, поскольку i = t уже на первой итерации. А пока это условие истинно, цикл не остановится. То есть он бесконечный. Чтобы исправить это можно либо поменять условие на `i <= t+5`, либо цикл со счётчиком for можно вообще заменить на цикл с проверкой условия while. Во втором случае кода будет меньше при том же функционале.
Теперь по поводу `alert(++c);` Зачем Вы увеличиваете значение `с` перед выводом? В этом нет смысла, ведь значения `с` высчитываются для i на каждой итерации. По смыслу задачи c=f(i), а у Вас сейчас: c=f(i)+1. Я уж молчу про то, что alert не делает таблицу, он выбрасывает пользователю всплывающее окошко с одним значением, которое блокирует дальнейшее выполнение программы, пока не будет закрыто.
Формула перевода градусов по Фаренгейту в градусы по Цельсию у Вас неправильная.
Набросал тут исправление для Вашей задачки:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function temp() {
    var t = document.getElementById("t").value;

    //Делаем заголовок таблицы
    document.write("<table border=1>");
    document.write("<tr><th>F</th><th>C</th></tr>");

    for (var i = t; i <= +t+5; i++) {
      var c = (i - 32) * (5/9);
      document.write('<tr><td>'+i+'</td><td>'+c+'</td></tr>');
    }

    document.write('</table>');
  }
</script>
<form id='temp'>
<input id="t" placeholder="Введите температуру по F"/>
<button onclick='temp()'>Перевести температуру</button>
</form>
```

Я сделал стандартную рамку для таблицы и объединил html и js в один файл только чтобы быстрее разобраться, не отвлекаясь на разделение кода по файлам и оформление. Переделаете как Вам надо. Унарный плюс в условии `i<=+t+5` необходим для правильного преобразования типов. Без него, если, например t=7, t+5=75, а с ним - t+5=12.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function temp() {
  var t = +document.getElementById('t').value;
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var a = (t+i) + " ==== "+((t+i) - 32) * (5/9) + "<br>";
    document.write(a); 
  }
}
```

```html
    <input id="t" placeholder="Введите температуру по F"/>
    <button onclick='temp()'>Перевести температуру</button>
```

Comment: А можно все вывести в одном  alert ?

Comment: Можна виводить куда надо. Так подейдет?